# Remove list items within another list

Tags: c#, linq

I think I'm halfway there in that I have managed to select all the items I want to remove. How do I actually remove them without resorting to a foreach loop?

```
List<LadderMatchItem> matchResults = (from p in ladder.Participants
                                      from m in p.MatchResults
                                      where m.Id == command.LadderMatchId
                                      select m).ToList();
```

edit: Simplified Class structure

```
public class Ladder
{       
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IList<LadderParticipant> Participants { get; set; }
}

public class LadderParticipant
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<LadderMatchItem> MatchResults { get; set; }
}

public class LadderMatchItem
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    public LadderMatchResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you are halfway but we are not so we need to look from start can you please provide class structure for classes?

Comment: added class structure.

Comment: you have to remove those whose Id matching with ladder id?

Comment: Use `!=` not equals

Comment: Those who's id matches command.LadderMatchId.  As I say the result of the query gives me the correct list of LadderMatchItem that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try is change your condition

```
ladder.Participants.ForEach(x => x.MatchResults.RemoveAll(ele => ele.Id == command.LadderMatchId));
```

Comment: I don't see how that will remove the items.  The matching items need to be removed from p.MatchResults.

Comment: yep perfect!  Thanks so much.  You just need to change the !=, to == in your answer.

Comment: @BMills happy to help